# Not able to get accurate location from google map and onLocationChanged method is not called significantly

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]i am now doing an application in that i have to show the route to the users where i have to give voice guidance when ever the user reaches particular latlng.  Those latlng will be captured already and i have to make the users to follow it up.

here  i have added my login in onLocationChanged method where i just take the current location when ever the onLocationChanged method is called and i will compare with the list of latlng that i will get from back end , if any latlng is less then 50 meters i will just let the mobile to instruct the user via voice as we see in google map

Here my problem is, in google map i am not able to get the exact location on the map , it is not accurate, when i ride a bike the method is not called at that point where it supposed to tell the route to the user

i tried so many types of maps logics , the onloaction changed is not called properly and the location is not updated properly

i see this problem even in google map to , if you see the google map even there the location is not updated accurately, it says approximately

Now i want the onLocationChanged method to be called when ever i move a bit from one place to another only then i can fulfill the project require ment

Some times the onLocationChanged Method is called when i pass through that particular location, so facing lot of issues in updating the route and calling the onLocationChanged method in my project

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        distance = new ArrayList<>();
        location.setAccuracy(1f);
        if (mActivity.mMap != null) {
            mActivity.mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
       /* if (mActivity.mMap != null) {
            Location loc = mActivity.mMap.getMyLocation();
            double lat = loc.getLatitude();
            double lng = loc.getLongitude();
        }*/
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng currentLatLang = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
//        mActivity.mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLang));
//        if (mActivity.isZoom) {
//            mActivity.isZoom = false;
        if (mActivity.mMap != null) {
            mActivity.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLatLang));
        }
//        }
//        mActivity.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLang));

        for (int i = 0; i < mActivity.routeDirection.size(); i++) {

//            Location currentLocation = new Location(location);
           /* currentLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
            currentLocation.setLongitude(longitude);*/

            Location temp = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            temp.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(mActivity.routeDirection.get(i).getRouteArray().getLat()));
            temp.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(mActivity.routeDirection.get(i).getRouteArray().getLng()));


            double threshHold = 23.0; // meters

            double curAndTempDistance = location.distanceTo(temp);
            distance.add((float) curAndTempDistance);
            mActivity.mCommentText.setText(distance.get(0) + "");

            if (curAndTempDistance < threshHold) {
                if (mActivity.isFromStartPoint) {
                    msg = mActivity.routeDirection.get(i).getStartToEndCommand();
                } else {
                    msg = mActivity.routeDirection.get(i).getEndToStartCommand();
                }
                mActivity.mCommentText.setText(msg + " " + curAndTempDistance);
                if (i != mActivity.previousInstruction) {
                    tts.speak(msg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
                mActivity.previousInstruction = i;
                break;
            } else {
                if (i == mActivity.previousInstruction) {
                    if (mActivity.isFromStartPoint && mActivity.routeDirection.size() == mActivity.previousInstruction) {
                        mActivity.previousInstruction = -1;
                        mActivity.isFromStartPoint = false;
                        // Rate this app

                    } else if (!mActivity.isFromStartPoint && mActivity.previousInstruction == 0) {
                        mActivity.previousInstruction = -1;
                        mActivity.isFromStartPoint = true;
                        //Rate this app

                    }
                }
            }


        }



mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0.1f, listener);
```

this is how i use my service class and calling method from activity . can i have some solution for this problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you using **High accuracy** mode for location on your phone?

Comment: How often do you request location changes and what accuracy did you use? See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Thanks @Stefan for your time, i have even checked with High accuracy too but i still get the same(Not getting accurate location)